# MySQL sets upload limit when phpMyAdmin is accessed from user account

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, image-uploading

The problem I have is that when I connect to phpMyAdmin which is stored in my website directory, the maximum file upload limit of a mediumblob in my table is limited to 2048KiB, even though it should be 16MiB.
But surprisingly when I open phpMyAdmin through a button in the CPanel on my hosting providers(GoDaddy) website, then phpMyAdmin is opened through a secure server and then somehow the maximum limit of a mediumblob is set to 16MiB, so everything works fine.
Because of this issue, when I connect to the mysql database through php, I cannot upload files larger than 2048KiB to my table even though technically I should be able to upload files up to 16MiB.

This is what I see when I login to phpMyAdmin thats in my websites folder, e.g -> (mywebsite).com/phpMyAdmin
[image]

This is what I see when I go to GoDaddy website, then go to Cpanel and then click on phpMyAdmin(this connects to phpMyAdmin from a secure server)
[image]

As you can clearly see that mediumblobs work as they are supposed to and can allow me to upload files up to 16MiB but ONLY when I use phpMyAdmin from GoDaddy's cpanel. 
How do I insert files into this table from a php script, because when I use my regular passcode to connect to the database, then I am not able to upload files larger than 2048KiB.
These are my php settings :
[image]

I have contacted GoDaddy's helpline services and spoke to some of the representatives for a few hours. Ultimately they just cut the call and could not provide any support.

My Question Again : ***How do I insert files into this table from a php script, because when I use my regular passcode to connect to and query the database, then I am not able to upload files larger than 2048KiB.***

Any help received is appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Go Daddy? Friends don't let friends ....

Comment: @O.Jones Never purchasing anything from Go Daddy again...

Comment: Instead of MEDIUMBLOB use LONGBLOB, then you should be able to upload a 32MB image (as thats the upload limit)

Comment: 2048KiB is most likely the max_post_size, though if you use a proper upload lib you can use chunking.

Comment: or rent a VPS then you can set what you like.. blaming your $2.99 per year host for resource limits makes no sense.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried changing it to longblob but it still doesnt increase and remains at 2048KiB. Btw It actually costs $20 per year over here.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Could you suggest a good lib for chunking the images?

Comment: Yeah it will, that's what you can upload within phpmyadmin, the datatype has nothing todo with phpmyadmin

Comment: http://www.plupload.com/ - plenty of others